# How to set the seo title tag on a page by page basis?

Tags: custom-post-types, advanced-custom-fields, title, seo

I am storing the SEO title with advanced-custom-fields.  How do i set the seo title tag within my single-mypost.php template.  This is the place where i can call get_field('title_tag');

I tried adding this to functions.php :

```
add_filter('wpseo_title', 'filter_product_wpseo_title');
function filter_product_wpseo_title($title) {
    if(  is_singular( 'my_post_type') ) {   
        $title = get_field("title_tag");
    }
    return $title;
}
```

Comment: And why don’t you just use one of SEO plugins?

Comment: And...? You can still set it programmatically using Yoast SEO for example...

Answer (score -1):

I added this to functions.php while having Yoast SEO activated, and then it worked!

```
add_filter('wpseo_title', 'filter_product_wpseo_title');
function filter_product_wpseo_title($title) {
    if(  is_singular( 'my_post_type') ) {   
        $title = get_field("title_tag");
    }
    return $title;
}
```

Comment: If you're using the `wpseo_title` hook, then that means you have WP SEO installed, and that plugin already has a field for setting the title, so why are you using a custom field for it?